# How to see PHP error stack trace/dump?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, amazon-ec2, lamp, debug

Currently my web application can print error when host on my local machine.

When I host it on Amazon EC2 server. The error page is empty/blank.

I want to see the error stack trace when run on EC2, how can I do that?

I'm using Ubuntu Natty 11.04 and LAMP Stack on my EC2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you post the contents of php.ini? This looks like a configuration issue. We will need to check that the web server can find the error log you defined in php.ini and that the web server has permissions to write to it. PHP silently fails if either condition isn't met...

Comment: http://code.namgivu.com/index-phpinfo.php is my `phpinfo`

Comment: You're not specifying an absolute path to the error log. This means that the webserver will asume that the error log is in document_root. (Someone correct me if I'm wrong)Try putting in path to the apache logs dir, restarting the server, and see if you get output.

Comment: @Mideiane I appreciate your help a lot. Though, if it were with more full information, I'll choose your answer as accepted. Thank you a lot! It's now works with full path.

Comment: @NamGiVU hm. OK.

Answer (score 2):

Open the php.ini file and change the following directives so it looks like this.

```
display_errors = On
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Then restart Apache and do something to cause an error, such as manually call `trigger_error('Test');` on a page.

**You should be aware this is bad practice for a production website.** These settings are fine in dev, where you *want* errors to be blatantly obvious, but for production you should be logging errors to a file which you review. This log file is defined with the `error_log` directive.

Comment: It's great. I think I better go with the `error_log` option.

Comment: I tried to alter my php.ini at `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` to include `error_log = php_errors.log`, `display_errors = On`, `error_reporting = E_ALL`; then I restart Apache via `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`. Then I refresh the error page: I can see the error printed on my web but I found no lines in `/etc/php5/apache2/php_errors.log`. Please help

Comment: The error in your page is identical to what you'd get in the error log anyways.